# How to avoid repeating Robolectric @Config?

Tags: robolectric

I have the following Robolectric annotation:

> @RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
>
> @Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21, packageName = "com.package.android")

Is there a way to call this from elsewhere so that I don't have to repeat it for every single test class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did next:

```
@Ignore("This is base class for Robolectric tests")
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
public abstract class RobolectricTestCaseTemplate 
{
}
```

And after we just inherit it:

```
AccountScreenFragmentPresenterTest extends RobolectricTestCaseTemplate 
{
...
}
```